# Catch the user that responses to an awaitMessages action

Tags: node.js, discord.js

in my discord bot, i have a command that scrambles a word, and the first user that responds in the chat gets a reward. i already made the command to await a message response, but how can i save who responded? heres my code so far

```
authorID = msg.author.id;
const filter = response => {
    return response.author.id === authorID;
}

msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
        max: 1,
        time: 5000
    })
    .then(mg2 => {
        if (mg2.first().content === "1") {

            msg.channel.send("you said 1");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the filter, you are only allowing the original msg author to enter, you should make it so it detects if the msg.content equals the unscrabbled word. Also you don't have `errors: ["time"]`.

```js
const filter = m => m.content === unscrabledWord;

msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 5000, errors: ["time"] })
    .then(collected => {
        const winner = collected.first().author;
        msg.channel.send(`${winner} Won!`)
    })
    .catch(() => msg.channel.send("Nobody guessed it"));
```